# How to use `const`ness in this example?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I have some code which implements graph algorithms; in particular, there are these snippets, which cause problems:

```
class Path{
private:
    const Graph* graph;

public:
    Path(Graph* graph_) : graph(graph_) {
        ...
    }
```

(which is supposed to create `Path` object with a constant pointer to a 
graph)

```
class GradientDescent{
private:
    const Graph graph;
public:
    Path currentPath;
    GradientDescent(const Graph& graph_) : graph(graph_), currentPath(Path(&graph_)) {}
```

(which is supposed to create a `GradientDescent` object that has a const `Graph` and a non-const `Path`)

The problem is, as I am just trying to figure out how to use `const`s, I get this error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Path'
    GradientDescent(const Graph& graph_) : graph(graph_), currentPath(Path(&graph_)) {}

longest_path.cpp:103:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const Graph *') would lose const qualifier
    Path(Graph* graph_) : graph(graph_) {
```

Comment: `Path(const Graph* graph_)`

Comment: You are taking the address from a `const&` so it must be a `const*`.

Comment: @krzaq I cant believe I've missed that... If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Path`'s constructor expects a pointer to non-`const` `Graph`.

To get rid of this problem simply change your constructor declaration:

```
Path(const Graph* graph_) : graph(graph_) {
    ...
}
```